# HTML : Enable Multiple Submission without refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wamp

I want to enhance my tool's page where as soon use click a button. Request goes to server and depending upon return type (fail/pass) i change color of button. No Refresh/page reload

Page has multiple buttons : some what like below.

```
Name       9-11  -  11-2      2-5

Resource1 - Button - Button - Button 

Resource2 - Button - Button - Button 

Resource1 - Button - Button - Button
```

I am a c++ programmer so you might feel i asked a simple question

Comment: What you're looking for is ajax.

Comment: you need ajax. I don't know what language you are using, so I don't know how it works. But for most part, this will be done in javascript...

Comment: Yeah ! Guys i read about Ajax , I think this is solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample of jQuery Ajax posting a `Form`. Personally, I'm unfamiliar with PHP but Ajax is the same no matter what. You just need to post to something that can return `Success = true` or `false`. This POST happens asynchronously so you don't get a page refresh unless you do something specific in the `success:` section.

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: yourUrlHere,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result.Success) {
                        // do nothing
                    }                           
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Of course you don't have to be doing a `POST` either, it could be a `GET`

```
type: 'GET',
```

And if you don't need to pass any data just leave `data:` section out. But if you want to specify the data you can with `data: { paramName: yourValue },`

The `cache: false,` line can be left out if you want to cache the page. Seeing as how you aren't going to show any changes you can remove that line. jQuery appends a unique value to the Url so as to keep it from caching. Specifying `type: "json",` or whatever your specific type is, is always a good idea but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the $.post or $.get functions in jquery

```
$.post("url",$("#myform").serialize());
```

Adding a callback function  as Fabrício Matté suggested

```
$.post("url",$("#myform").serialize(),function(data){alert(data);$("#myform").hide()//?Do something with the returned data here});
```

Comment: And a callback function, as he wants to manipulate the DOM based on the ajax call's response.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You will find an example of a form, a button a the necessary ajax processing php page. Try it out and let us know how it goes:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="my_form" id="my_form">
  <input type="submit" name="my_button" id="my_button" value="Submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function () {

    $('#my_form').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxpage.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) 
                    {
                        //THere was an error
                        if(result.error) 
                        {
                            //So apply 'red' color to button
                            $("#my_button").addClass('red');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //there was no error. So apply 'green' color
                            $("#my_button").addClass('green');  
                        }
                    }                           
            });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<?php 
//ajaxpage.php
//Do your processing here

if ( $processed )
{
    $error = false;
}
else
{
    $error = true;  
}

print json_encode(array('error' => $error));
die();

?>
```